# ruby on rails javascript asset path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Im just a little confused on why doesn't a controller specified js  file lets say post.js won't render  any of the java script like document.write("hello") in any of the post posts view  but then application.js does it for every view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because in your `application.html.erb` you are including `application.js` with  `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` but your controller specified javascripts will render only after the specific action is executed. For example if you are creating a new post and your form has `remote: true`, After the form is submitted it will  trigger the create action which will render `create.js.erb`.

Comment: thanks alot for replying , just so i can get my head around it i have alert("hello") in my post.js how would i change my syntax change in my posts controller/view so that it would work

Comment: @user3369264 can you please clarify what you actually want to do or update the question with some code?

Comment: yea sure , i want a js alert saying "post saved" when i save my post , but i don't want the java script code to be  inline but rather in the posts.js

Comment: I guess you creating a new post and when the post is created you want a javascript alert right?

Comment: First add remote:true in your form and the in your create action add if @post.save  respond_to do |format|  format.html  format.js  end and then create a javascript file create.js.erb inside app/views/Posts directory and write your alert msg inside the script. Note the name of the javascript file should be same as the action name

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to setup flash messages and display flash alerts like if @post.save redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Post created!'.